# CGPathRef to set of CGRects

Tags: macos, algorithm, cocoa, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I am looking some algorithm or some way or even some references which can enable me generate set of rectangles from CGPathRef.

Consider following cases:

Add a rectangle in path

> ```
> CGMutablePathRef pathref = CGPathCreateMutable();
> CGPathAddRect(pathref, NULL, CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 300));
> CGPathCloseSubpath(pathref);
> ```

In above case we have only one rectangle stored in path, so when we fill it only one rectangle is draw, thus algorithm returns the 1 rect.

Adding Circle/Ellipse to Path

> ```
> CGMutablePathRef pathref = CGPathCreateMutable();
> CGPathAddEllipseInRect(pathref, NULL, CGRectMake(10, 10, 500, 500));
> CGPathCloseSubpath(pathref);
> ```

In this case we have circle stored in path, so when we paint it we can imagine lot of retables are filled filled, thus algorithm returns the n rects.

Bit more complex path

```
CGMutablePathRef pathref = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(pathref, NULL, CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 300));
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(pathref, NULL, CGRectMake(10, 10, 500, 500));
CGPathCloseSubpath(pathref);
```

and so on.

In above question I am primarily interested in filling, may be later I will have work with stroke too. Hopefully similar approach as in filling should work.

Can someone guide me on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the blog post [Wrapping text around a shape with CoreText](http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-text-around-shape-with-coretext-540). The main routine in it is `copyRectangularPathsForPath:height:`, which takes an (almost) arbitrary path and returns you an array of rectangular paths of a given height that would fill it. The "almost" is because as written, it can't handle paths that would require disjoint multiple rectangles on the same line. This code could be extended to support those kinds of shapes, though.

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed. I do need disjoint multiple rectangles on the same line, but I can delay that part till I actually face the situation. Thanks again!